# How do I define the split_train_test in Python?

Tags: python-3.8

I am working on a python code to generate network traffic using GANs and I'm getting this error that split_train_test is not defined. I have imported train_test_split from sklearn.model_selection but it doesnt seem to work. What am I not doing right?
This is the error message;

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-153-a2836ba27bc4> in <module>
      9     cross_validation_flg = False
     10     benign_file = '../data/attack_normal_data/benign_data.csv'
---> 11     benign_model, benign_test_loader = run_main(benign_file, num_features=41)
     12     # Save the model checkpoint
     13     torch.save(benign_model.state_dict(), 'benign_model_epoches%d.ckpt' % num_epochs)

<ipython-input-147-e59bfccfe2c7> in run_main(input_file, num_features)
      5     dataset = TrafficDataset(input_file, transform=None, normalization_flg=True)
      6 
----> 7     train_sampler, test_sampler = split_train_test(dataset, split_percent=0.7, shuffle=True)
      8     cntr = Counter(dataset.y)
      9     print('dataset: ', len(dataset), ' y:', sorted(cntr.items()))

NameError: name 'split_train_test' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `train_test_split`

Reference the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)